# How to create Observable based on conditions

Tags: rx-java

Is there a way to create observables based on some conditions?

For example if I have `Observable.just(1, 2, 3, ..., n)` and if next emitted item is 1, then `doSomethingA`, if 5 then `doSomethignB` otherwise `doWithEverythingElse`.

Or am I asking too much? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` statement in `doOnNext`:

```
observable.doOnNext(i -> 
    if (i==1)
        doSomethingA();
    else if (i==5)
        doSomethingB();
    else 
        doWithEverythingElse());
```

Comment: That would work, but kind of hoped something more elegant :)

Comment: An issue was opened on RxJava about this topic a while back but I couldn't find it. Anyway I believe the consensus was that api additions for this purpose didn't improve much on the pattern above so were abandoned. You could try to convince again if you have an idiom you'd like to see implemented.